# Why reflection occurs in crystals?

Tags: solid-state-physics, reflection, diffraction, crystals, x-ray-crystallography

Why do reflections occur in crystals? Why not transmission only? How can atomic planes work as mirrors?

Comment: Each scattering center (atom) in the lattice acts as its own source of spherical waves that interfere with each other, like a diffraction grating. The "atomic planes are mirrors" derivation of the Bragg condition is essentially a *heuristic* that gets the right answer and allows for nice visualiztaions. Really, you should look at derivations of the Laue condition, which is more in line with what's really going on. I like the derivation in Ashcroft and Mermin.

Comment: to add to the above by @march note too that coherent sources distributed periodically and uniformly in a plane grid with spacing much less than the wavelength say $1/20^{th}$ will form an essentially pane wave whose direction is determined by the phase ramp across the array. This idea is partly what a phased array is all about.